# Deploying multiple Angular applications on IIS 10

Tags: angular, iis, deployment

I need to deploy three Angular applications to the IIS 10. Routing needs to be functional for all situations and for all apps. The applications are in separate folders like 'first-app', 'second-app' and 'third-app' inside the folder which represents a physical path for the application.

For example, if I have a 'home' route inside the first app, navigating to the
localhost/first-app/home should work without giving me the 404 error.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploy your three application as virtual applications in your default web site. In the `index.html` change the base url value accordingly. For example, for the first app, the base url will be

```
<base href="http://localhost/first-app/">
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution is fine for me. Additionally, I had to set up separate web config files in each directory with url rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng build --prod --deployUrl="/first-app/" --baseHref="/first-app/"
```